# Python: How to iterate over a list of dictionaries and add each dictionary as value to a new dictionary with a unique key - no repeats

Tags: python, list, dictionary, append, iteration

Have a list of dicts. I want to add a key to each dict and append them all to one dict. How do i do this without getting repeats of the same entry into new dict?

I tried this code:

```
# a_list is a list of dictionaries
# category_name is a string

def make_dict(a_list, category_name=None):

    a_dict = {}

    for item in a_list:
        for i in range(0, len(a_list)):
            a_dict.setdefault(category_name + str(i+1), item)

    return a_dict
```

But while it creates a new name, the first object in the list is repeated for the total number of objects in the list.

```
{
    "Open Port 1": {
        "LocalAddress": "::",
        "LocalPort": 58448,
        "RemoteAddress": "::",
        "RemotePort": 0,
        "State": 100
    },
    "Open Port 2": {
        "LocalAddress": "::",
        "LocalPort": 58448,
        "RemoteAddress": "::",
        "RemotePort": 0,
        "State": 100
    },
    "Open Port 3": {
        "LocalAddress": "::",
        "LocalPort": 58448,
        "RemoteAddress": "::",
        "RemotePort": 0,
        "State": 100
    }, ... etc
```

Any ideas of how to solve this issue?

Comment: But how?? Where is the "i" index being incremented? How is it not just always 0?

Answer (score 2):

With the code you posted - you'll get the same key `"Open Port 1"` reassigned with each next dict cause the counter `i` is not incremented:

```
i = 0
for item in a_list:
    a_dict.setdefault(category_name + str(i+1), item)
return a_dict
```

The corrected way would be:

```
i = 0
for item in a_list:
    a_dict.setdefault(category_name + str(i+1), item)
    i += 1
return a_dict
```

**But**, in your simple case you may just go with dict comprehension:

```
a_dict = {category_name + str(i): d for i, d in enumerate(a_list, 1)}
```

Comment: OP clearly didn't post the code they were using so actual problem is probably elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah got it fixed straight away.

```
for item in a_list:
        a_dict[(category_name + str(i))] = item
        i += 1
    return a_dict
```

Comment: You could use `enumerate` to be even more elegant: `for i, item in enumerate(a_list):` Then you don't have to increment `i` explicitly.